# How to create a dashed line in AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I want to draw a dashed line, but can't find the best way for this issue.

Comment: You can use an `image` something like [this](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/fIhbtW17lU8/maxresdefault.jpg) and create an object of that image using and engine APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an in-built function, so you will have to do that "manually":

1. Choose the coordinates for the start of the line.
2. Choose the coordinates for the end of the line.
3. Using those two vectors, calculate the slope between those two points.
4. Recursively (in a loop) use the slope to calculate the next coordinate along the path to place a dot / dash.
5. Draw a very short (e. g. 1px) line segment representing the dot / dash.

[[source]](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/dotted-lines-t1754.html)